# Why can I only add a gesture recognizer outside of enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a gesture recognizer to all 8 buttons in my IBOutletCollection of UIButtons.

```
for (UIButton *stockButton in stockButtonCollection) {
    [stockButton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
}
```

Seems like that should work to me... yet it doesn't.

However, if I add this right underneath the loop

```
[[stockButtonCollection objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
```

Then it works?

Can anyone explain? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**  Hmm, I can see it's not an enumeration issue actually..  if underneath the loop I add:
[[stockButtonCollection objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
[[stockButtonCollection objectAtIndex:1] addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];

The gesture recognizer only gets applied to the second one (objectAtIndex:1) and doesn't work on the first one.    Basically it only works for the last one I add it too.

Can anyone explain why that is and how I can do what I'm trying to do? :)
Thanks

**UPDATE 2:**
Alright here's my longpressGesture handler

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

UIButton *myButton = (id)gestureRecognizer.view;

[myButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

So I guess its something to do with a single gesture recognizer being sent or something.  I don't fully understand it, but does anyone know how to do what I'm attempting?  I want all 8 buttons to disable if held down

**Update 3**
Ahh, neglected to post my gesture recognizer init...  here it is

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:(id)self];
```

Comment: Please show how you create the gesture recogniser, and also how you know it isn't applied to the other buttons - have you logged the gestureRecognizers for each button, or is it just not responding to the gesture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A gesture recognizer can only be attached to a single view. You'll have to create a new one for each view.